# command gulp error "assert.js:42 throw new errors.AssertionError"

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

I have a simple install gulp livereload:

gulp
assert.js:42
  throw new errors.AssertionError({
  ^

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task function must be specified
    at Gulp.set [as _setTask] (c:\testjses6\node_modules\undertaker\lib\set-task.js:10:3)
    at Gulp.task (c:\testjses6\node_modules\undertaker\lib\task.js:13:8)
    at Object. (c:\testjses6\gulpfile.js:21:6)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)

Comment: You have to show your gulpfile.js.

Answer (score 4):

The problem you are encountering is that you are running `gulp v4.0` using `gulp 3` syntax. The `AssertionError: Task function must be specified` error comes from the fact that `gulp.task` has changed and the 3 parameters signature was removed. In short, tasks that look like the one below will need to be changed to remove the `[]` parameter:

```
gulp.task('default', ['build'], function () {
  return runSequence(['watch', 'karma-watch']);
});
```

[This article](https://blog.wearewizards.io/migrating-to-gulp-4-by-example) will help you migrate to `gulp 4` syntax.

If you'd like a simple fix to your problem, without having to make changes to your `gulpfile.js`, run the following command to downgrade your version of `gulp` from version 4 to `3.9.1`:

```
npm install gulp@3.9.1 --save
```

Assuming all goes well you should no longer see the Assertion error.

Comment: Reversing to the older version is was a solution to me.

Answer (score 1):

gulp 4 creates many issues with old implementations, modify you tasks declarations:

- Old syntax:

  ```
  gulp.task('a', ['b', 'c'], function () { // do something })
  ```
- New syntax:

  ```
  gulp.task('a', gulp.series(gulp.parallel('b', 'c'), function () {  // do something }))
  ```

Hope this helps someone, I figured it after spending hours troubleshooting.